# decomposition of cokernel

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Lets work over $\mathbb Z$ and represent maps $f:\mathbb Z^l \longrightarrow \mathbb Z^n$ as matrices. For the following matrices
write an equivalent diagonal matrix. I want to write a decomposition of $\operatorname{coker}f$ as a direct
sum of cyclic $\mathbb Z$ modules.
$(a)$ $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$
$(b)$ $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$
$(c)$ $\begin{pmatrix}5&8&3\\3&6&3\end{pmatrix}$
$(d)$ For this one show that if a does not divide b then you can pick a different basis with
the 1; 1 entry having smaller absolute value.
$\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Please check my edit. Should the third matrix be square? waht is $(d)$?

Comment: is there an example `(d)` ?  Example `(c)` is not even square.

Comment: the Babgen;s edit is correct. please look at his edit.

Comment: this is my homework and I don't sure what is the final solution.for example in part a the coker f is Z mod a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The co-kernel of a linear map $f:\mathbb{Z}^l \to \mathbb{Z}^n$ is the quotient of the co-domain by the image 
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}^m }{ f(\mathbb{Z}^l)}$$

This is a homework, so I left out some details.

### (a)

Let's calculate the image of the first matrix in $\mathbb{Z}^2$:

\[ \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}m\\n\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}ma + nb\\0\end{pmatrix} \in \begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}\\0\end{pmatrix}\]

[Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) shows that $\{ ma + nb: m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = (a,b)\mathbb{Z}$ which could be a proper subset of $\mathbb{Z}$.

The cokernel is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ modulo this image space:

$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}^2}{(a,b)\, \mathbb{Z} \times 1} \simeq \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(a,b)\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{Z} $$

### (b)

Let $a = (a,b)\;a'$ and $ b =(a,b)\;b' $.  We can pull the greatest common factor out of our calculation.

\[ \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}\\\mathbb{Z}\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z} + 
\begin{pmatrix}b \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z} 
 = (a,b) \left[ \begin{pmatrix}a' \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z} + 
\begin{pmatrix}b' \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z} \right] \]

In fact, this matrix is diagonal over $\mathbb{Z}$ so the image is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the co-kernel is $\vec{\mathbf{0}}$.

### (c)

The two vectors look "relatively prime" i.e. linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ so I will guess the image is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the cokernel is $\mathbb{Z}^{3-2} = \mathbb{Z}$.

In light of the comments, we could try row-reduction...

$$ \begin{pmatrix}5&8&3\\3&6&3\end{pmatrix} \to 
\begin{pmatrix}3&6&3 \\ 2&2&0\end{pmatrix} \to 
\begin{pmatrix}-3&0&3 \\ 2&2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

I will revise my guess to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: The fact that they are independent does not mean that they span $\mathbb{Z}^2$. For example, $(2,0)$ and $(0,3)$ are independent, but the do not span $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Comment: Thank you John and Thank you Dennis your guidance is helpfull but I am new here and O did not know all of the rolls of this web site and I did not learned latex yet so I can not put ather question. could you please help me guys?